# Identifying .doc/.docx files that contain images

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, images, evernote, docx

I'm moving my notes to evernote. To this end I need to convert .doc/.docx files to rtf. The reason for this is that I have a script to import rtf into evernote. However, some of my .doc/.docx files contain images.

Is there any way to identify which .doc/.docx files contain images without viewing them all? I have thousands. This way I can simply open the few that have images and copy/paste the entire content straight into evernote.

Should say that I'm using OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Where do .doc files store images?

Word `doc` files are actually zipped and then put into a container format. They store media somewhere in this compiled file format, probably right after the `doc` format's header. After the image data, there's your real document as a zip-compatible folder.

[image: file layout]

So when you try to unzip a `doc` file, you get an excess number of bytes at the beginning. These are your images (plus the format header). You could now attempt to `unzip` the file and check the excess amount of bytes.

```
charon:test werner$ unzip -c images.doc > /dev/null
warning [images.doc]:  47166 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile

charon:test werner$ unzip -c noimages.doc > /dev/null
warning [noimages2.doc]:  6060 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
```

Through testing, I found the header of "plaintext" Word documents to be 6060 bytes large (some are a bit larger though). We can try to exploit it for determining whether there's an image inside a document. Let's just say 8000 bytes — since real images will definitely have more than a few KB.

---

### What about .docx files?

With the Office 2007 format (`docx`), this is much easier. These are actual zipped files, and any Word file that contains embedded media of any kind (images, video) will include the `file.docx/word/media` directory.  So, we just need to unzip the `docx` files and check if that directory exists.

---

### A script to check for images

- Create a new empty file, call it `docx-images.rb`, and paste the following content:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby
  require 'open3'
  TEMPDIR = "/tmp/word/"

  # check for docx files
  Dir.glob("**/*.docx").each do |file|
    system("rm -rf '#{TEMPDIR}'")
    system("unzip '#{file}' -d #{TEMPDIR} > /dev/null")
    if File.directory?("#{TEMPDIR}/word/media/")
      puts file
    end
  end

  # check for doc files
  Dir.glob("**/*.doc").each do |file|
    stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("unzip -c '#{file}' > /dev/null")
    info = stderr.readlines[0]
    info = info.gsub(" extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile", "").gsub(/warning\s\[.*\]:\s+/, "")
    if info.to_i > 8000 # assume a little more than usual header size
      puts file
    end
  end
  ```
- Save it somewhere, preferably in a folder where you want to begin your search for `docx` files from, maybe your `Documents` folder.
- Now, open up *Terminal.app*, and use `cd ~/Documents` to go there.
- Type `ruby docx-images.rb`, and it will recursively scan your `Documents` folder for `docx` and `doc` files. It'll unzip the former to `/tmp/word`, and check if they contain embedded media. The latter are just unzipped to `/dev/null`, thus leaving no traces behind.
- You'll end up with a list of those with embedded media.

---

### Proof

To prove that this works, I created four files. One with images, one without images – both as `doc` and `docx`:

[image: proof]

Then, running the script:

```
charon:test werner$ ruby docx-images.rb 
images.docx
images.doc
```

Clearly, the script could be improved to check for actual images in that `media` folder, but it's unlikely it exists unless the file really contains any media. The same goes for the "6060" bytes check. It's a hack, but it works for me.

Of course, the script depends on the implementation of `unzip` on the respective system, but it works for the OS X version.

Comment: many thanks for the reply. I copied the code into a new document into one of my folders that contained .doc files and sub folders with .doc files in. I then use the terminal to navigate to the folder and run the ruby code. The terminal window then listed a number of .doc files. Would I be right in assuming that this list should contain those .doc files that contain images? If this is the case then something is not quite right as I got a complete list of the files in the folders and sub folders. I should add that some .doc files will be in 97 format.

Comment: So you got a list of *every* `.doc` file instead of just those with the images? Can you run `unzip -c some-file.doc > /dev/null` for one of these files that were misclassified and tell me if there's another offset than 6060 bytes?

Comment: `Simons-MacBook-Pro:7000-Acts and the Early church Simon$ unzip -c 7000-TROAS.doc > /dev/null
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  7000-TROAS.doc may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of 7000-TROAS.doc or
        7000-TROAS.doc.zip, and cannot find 7000-TROAS.doc.ZIP, period.`

Comment: Hm, that makes me believe these files weren't created with the same version of Word that I have (in that case, 2011) — but "Word 97-2003" is one kind of file format that should be the same regardless of the type. Of course my script will fail since it assumes the 6060 bytes header for all files *without* images. Maybe you can supply an example of a document that has images, and one that doesn't?

Comment: How do I send them to you?

Comment: http://ge.tt/8AfKxLG?c

Comment: These are `.dot` templates, not `.doc` documents. When you convert them to actual `.doc` documents, they include a 6570 byte header. So, it might be reasonable to say that any excess of under 10 000 bytes is a non-image Document, but `.dot` files just work differently.

Comment: many thanks. I ran a doc to docx conversion and everything works great now. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows**:

- **Renaming the .docx to .zip, opening the zip file and extracting the images (Best way!).**
- Then look for the image under `\zipfile\word\media` for the image.

[Reference](http://cnedelcu.blogspot.sg/2013/02/top-3-ways-to-extract-images-from-word-docx-doc-document.html)